# NativeScript DepreciationWarning : parse() is deprecated. Use Builder.parse() instead

Tags: nativescript

After upgrading to NS 6.3.0 I am getting this warning : 
parse() is deprecated. Use Builder.parse() instead

Comment: Are you using a beta release? tns-core-modules `v6.1.2` is the latest as of today. Still if you are using `parse()`, use `Builder.parse()`, if it's not your code but from any plugin then the author should take care of it before upcoming releases.

Comment: thanks @Manoj
Yes, I am using beta release. I have been struggling with slowing down after upgrade 6.1.2 then I have been checking with the beta releases to compare.
I am not using parse(), it should be a plugin then.